# oh-my-posh theme: cant identify the cause of question mark

Tags: json, powershell-core, unicode-escapes, oh-my-posh

I am very new to this, but I am trying to make my own oh-my-posh theme (basically by comparing, copying and trying sections from other themes and combining them). I am using pwsh and I am using JetBrainsMono Nerd Font.

My theme works fine so far, but for the git functionality I am seeing this question mark when I have unstaged files. The git code section in the JSON looks like this:

```
    {
      "background": "#00C853",
      "background_templates": [
          "{{ if or (.Working.Changed) (.Staging.Changed) }}#FFEB3B{{ end }}",
          "{{ if and (gt .Ahead 0) (gt .Behind 0) }}#FFCC80{{ end }}",
          "{{ if gt .Ahead 0 }}#B388FF{{ end }}",
          "{{ if gt .Behind 0 }}#B388FF{{ end }}"
      ],
      "foreground": "#000000",
      "powerline_symbol": "\ue0b0",
      "properties": {
          "fetch_stash_count": true,
          "fetch_status": true
      },
      "style": "powerline",
      "template": " {{ .HEAD }}{{ if .Staging.Changed }}<#FF6F00> \uf046 {{ .Staging.String }}</>{{ end }}{{ if and (.Working.Changed) (.Staging.Changed) }} |{{ end }}{{ if .Working.Changed }} \uf044 {{ .Working.String }}{{ end }}{{ if gt .StashCount 0 }} \ueb4b {{ .StashCount }}{{ end }} ",
      "type": "git"
    }
```

You can see the output here:

[image]

I have tried replacing all the \u... symbols, but they apparently are not the problem. Can someone lend me a hand here?

**MRE**:
JSON of the theme:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh/main/themes/schema.json",
  "blocks": [
    {
      "alignment": "left",
      "segments": [
        {
          "background": "#07585c",
          "foreground": "#ffffff",
          "leading_diamond": "\ue0b6",
          "style": "diamond",
          "template": " {{ .UserName }}@{{ .HostName }} ",
          "trailing_diamond": "\ue0b0",
          "type": "session"
        },
        {
          "background": "#444444",
          "foreground": "#E4E4E4",
          "properties": {
            "style": "full"
          },
          "style": "diamond",
          "template": " {{ .Path }} ",
          "type": "path"
        },
        {
          "background": "#00C853",
          "background_templates": [
              "{{ if or (.Working.Changed) (.Staging.Changed) }}#FFEB3B{{ end }}",
              "{{ if and (gt .Ahead 0) (gt .Behind 0) }}#FFCC80{{ end }}",
              "{{ if gt .Ahead 0 }}#B388FF{{ end }}",
              "{{ if gt .Behind 0 }}#B388FF{{ end }}"
          ],
          "foreground": "#000000",
          "powerline_symbol": "\ue0b0",
          "properties": {
              "fetch_stash_count": true,
              "fetch_status": true
          },
          "style": "powerline",
          "template": " {{ .HEAD }}{{ if .Staging.Changed }}<#FF6F00> \uf046 {{ .Staging.String }}</>{{ end }}{{ if and (.Working.Changed) (.Staging.Changed) }} |{{ end }}{{ if .Working.Changed }} \uf044 {{ .Working.String }}{{ end }}{{ if gt .StashCount 0 }} \ueb4b {{ .StashCount }}{{ end }} ",
          "type": "git"
        },
        {
          "background": "#575656",
          "foreground": "#d6deeb",
          "properties": {
            "style": "roundrock",
            "threshold": 0
          },
          "style": "diamond",
          "template": " {{ .FormattedMs }}",
          "trailing_diamond": "\ue0b4",
          "type": "executiontime"
        }
      ],
      "type": "prompt"
    },
    {
      "alignment": "right",
      "overflow": "break",
      "segments": [
        {
          "background": "#d6deeb",
          "foreground": "#011627",
          "leading_diamond": "\ue0b6",
          "style": "diamond",
          "template": "\uf489  {{ .Name }} ",
          "type": "shell"
        },
        {
          "background": "#234d70",
          "foreground": "#d6deeb",
          "properties": {
            "time_format": "15:04:05"
          },
          "style": "diamond",
          "template": " \ue641 {{ .CurrentDate | date .Format }}",
          "trailing_diamond": "\ue0b4",
          "type": "time"
        },
        {
          "background": "#306998",
          "foreground": "#FFE873",
          "leading_diamond": "\ue0b2",
          "style": "diamond",
          "template": "\ue235  {{ if .Error }}{{ .Error }}{{ else }}{{ if .Venv }}{{ .Venv }} {{ end }}{{ .Full }}{{ end }}",
          "trailing_diamond": "<transparent,#306998>\ue0b2</>",
          "type": "python"
        }
      ],
      "type": "prompt"
    },
    {
      "alignment": "left",
      "newline": true,
      "segments": [
        {
          "foreground": "#22da6e",
          "foreground_templates": ["{{ if gt .Code 0 }}#ef5350{{ end }}"],
          "properties": {
            "always_enabled": true
          },
          "style": "plain",
          "template": "\ue285\ue285",
          "type": "status"
        }
      ],
      "type": "prompt"
    }    
  ],
  "final_space": true,
  "version": 2
}
```

Open `pwsh`, make a folder, run `git init`, create a file (e.g. `New-Item bar.txt`), see the Git Powerline block change from green to yellow and this icon appear (there will be a "1" instead of a "2" if you only created one file in your git directory). To have the same output, install `JetBrainsMono Nerd Font`, but `CascaydiaCove Nerd Font` gives the same problem.
Also you should have the lines

```
Import-Module posh-git
oh-my-posh init pwsh --config "$env:POSH_THEMES_PATH/theme-name.omp.json" | Invoke-Expression
```

in your `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `{{ .Working.String }}` which prefixes the counts of untracked/modified/deleted files with their respective symbol. In the case of untracked, the symbol is `?` by default (specifically, the *template* is `?%d`). This is one of the gotchas of staged vs working environments, as we might think of a new file as "added" (and thus expect the `+` symbol) but in reality the file isn't added until it's been staged and until then it's untracked.

Oh-My-Posh provides a property in the [git segment](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/segments/git), `status_formats`, which you can read more about in the [fetching information](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/segments/git#fetching-information) section of the docs. It maps to the [status template properties](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/segments/git#status) so simply provide a template override for `.Untracked`, for example:

```
// In blocks[i].segments
{
  "type": "git",
  "properties": {
    "status_formats": {
      "Untracked": "+%d"
    }
  }
  // Template, configs, etc.
}
```